# I got an error when i add the method "FirestoreConnect"

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a small react native app, when i add some code to connect my component with firebase, it shows me this error:

> Invariant Violation: Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput,
       Keyboard, KeyboardAvoidingView, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose} from 'redux';
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';

import {addChat, deleteChat} from '../src/actions/chat_action';

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Chat Screen',
  };
   state = {
       chat_input: "",
   }

   onNewChat = () => {

       this.props.addChat(
           this.state.chat_input
       )
       this.setState({
           chat_input: ""
       });
       Keyboard.dismiss();
   }

   renderItem = ( {item} ) => {
       return (
           <View style={styles.row}>
               <Text style={styles.message} >{item.msg}</Text>
               <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.button}
                  onPress={this.props.deleteChat(item.id)}
                >
                  <Image
                    source={require('../assets/images/trash2.png')}
                    fadeDuration={0}
                    style={{width: 20, height: 20}}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>
       );
   }

  render() {
    const { thread } = this.props || []

       if (!thread) {
           return 
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Loading...</Text>
            </View>
       }
    return ( 
       <View style={styles.container}>
               <FlatList
                   data={thread}
                   renderItem={this.renderItem}
                   inverted
                   keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}  
               />
               <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
                   <View style={styles.footer}>
                       <TextInput
                           value={this.state.chat_input}
                           onChangeText={text => this.setState({ chat_input: text })}
                           style={styles.input}
                           underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                           placeholder="Type something nice"
                       />
                       <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onNewChat.bind(this)}>
                           <Text style={styles.send}>Send</Text>
                       </TouchableOpacity>
                   </View>
               </KeyboardAvoidingView>
           </View>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
   //thread: state.chatReducer.thread,
   thread: state.firestore.ordered.chat 
 }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
   addChat: (newChat) => dispatch(addChat(newChat)),
   deleteChat: (id) =>dispatch(deleteChat(id)),
 }
}

//export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (SettingsScreen)
export default compose(
   connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
   firestoreConnect([
       { collection: 'chat'},
   ]))(SettingsScreen);
```

Error :

[image]

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: It's saying that your SettingsScreen component is supposed to render some UI but it isn't.

Comment: @MikeM it contains actually some ui, it works without the method firestore connect, but when i add this method it shows that error.

Comment: Well, again, the error is saying that SettingsScreen is expected to render something and is not.  It may be throwing an error in the render method.  You may want to post the code for SettingsScreen.

Comment: @MikeM ok i just posted the hole code

Comment: It looks like the `(!thread)` case may need to have parentheses around the return

Comment: @MikeM oh that's correct ! its working now, thanks man.